# Special characters replacement function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function that replaces special characters with normal characters.

When I type a period `.` it's changed to `a`

Example : `info@example.com` is changed to `info@exampleacom`

What am I doing wrong?

```
function retiraAcento(palavra, obj) {
   com_acento = 'áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ';
   sem_acento = 'aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC';
   nova = '';
   for (i = 0; i < palavra.length; i++) {
       if (com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i, 1)) >= 0) {
           nova += sem_acento.substr(com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i, 1)), 1);
       } else {
           nova += palavra.substr(i, 1);
       }
   }
   //obj.value = nova.toUpperCase();
   obj.value = nova
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(":input").live('blur', function () {
       retiraAcento(this.value, this);
   });
});
```

Comment: Declare UTF-8 encoding. Use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Pages are all on UTF-8

Comment: declare it though ... `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Well, i have already this on   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) accepts a *regular expression* as an argument, not a dumb string. The character `.` has special meaning inside a regular expression; it means "match any character".

Therefore when your code ends up doing `com_acento.search(".")` the result is always `0`: the dot matches the first character. In addition, there are other characters with special meaning in regular expressions which will also cause your code to not work correctly.

Solve your problem by using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead of `search`.